# Unitary matrix and matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, inequalities

Dear all,

Suppose U and V are unitary matrix, A and B are positive definite,

Does:

$UAU^{-1} < VBV^{-1}$

implies   $A< B$

and vice versa?

Comment: What do you mean with $A<B$? Are you comparing term by term? Moreover, Do $U$ and $V$ diagonalize $A$ and $B$ respectively and you are comparing the diagonal terms?

Comment: I mean by A < B is  (B-A) > 0  or (B-A) is positive definite. U and V not necessarily diagonalize A and B, just to make them block diagonal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: think of the case of $A$, $B$ diagonal; $U$ identity, and $V$ a permutation operator.